# Read the next char in a StreamReader

Tags: c#

how to read the next character with a  streamreader and continue with the index before ?
Example, if the file has "Hello", i want for the 1st iteration get H and be able to get E without ruining my loop.
if i do read() i will lose the current index, hope i made it clear for you guys.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inpFil.Pth))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0 )
    { 
        char c = (char)sr.Read();
        char r = (char)sr.Read();
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the equivalent of "current" and "next" chars for the loop?

Comment: `Peek` - like you are already using...

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, and i dont want to lose the current one

Comment: @mjwills, but to i will need to use  read() to read it and i will lose the current one, and for the next loop i 'll get i+2

Comment: After the read(), you have the current one. You'll not loose it. In your code, the first iteration, `c` is "H" and `r` is "e". You have not lost anything. You want to go through your code step by step using a debugger.

Comment: I think the requirement is a loop that maintains (current, next) values such that for any iteration of the loop, the following iteration has `current` set to this iteration's `next`, and `next` will be set to the following character. You cannot implement that if you have two reads inside the loop. You must have only one read, and manipulate `current` and `next` variables to keep the state from one iteration to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after something like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inpFil.Pth"))
{
    if (sr.Peek() < 0)
        return; // No data.

    char current = (char)sr.Read(); // Can't be -1 due to Peek() test above.

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        char next = (char)sr.Read(); // Can't be -1 due to Peek() test above.

        // Add code here to do something with current and next.

        current = next;
    }

    // Add code here to handle the special case of the last char in
    // the file, where you have 'current' but no 'next'.
}
```

Note that in this implementation `current` will never reach the last character in the file, because in that case `next` would not exist. You might want to add special handling for the last character.

You could also rearrange the code slightly so that you can use `.Peek()` instead of having to maintain `current` and `next`. It's up to you whether you think this is easier to read:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("inpFil.Pth"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        char current = (char)sr.Read();
        
        if (sr.Peek() < 0) // No next?
        {
            // Add code here to handle 'current' for special "last char" case.
            break;
        }

        char next = (char)sr.Peek();

        // Add code here to do something with current and next.
    }
}
```